# If $f(x) \le \mu$ for all $x$ in $S$ and $x_0$ is a limit point of $S$ at which $f$ is continuous, then $f(x_0) \le \mu$.

Tags: calculus

I'm really lost here and not sure how to use the information given in the problem about $x_0$ being a limit point. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is continuous, then $f(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) \le \lim_{x\to x_0} \mu =\mu$.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a proof by contradiction:

If $f(x_0) = \mu + 2\epsilon > \mu$, then by continuity of $f$, there exists a neighbourhood $V_\epsilon$ of $x_0$ such that $f(V) \subset [f(x_0)-\epsilon, f(x_0)+\epsilon]$

But $x_0$ is a limit point of $S$, that means that $S\cap V \neq \emptyset$

So there exists $x\in S$ such that $f(x) \in f(V) = [f(x_0)-\epsilon, f(x_0)+\epsilon]$. Hence $f(x) > \mu$: contradiction